# Error Servlet en Java

Tags: java, web, jsp, servlets

### quiero realizar una comprobación de que tengo problemas para acceder a la clase Servlet una vez levantado el servidor, utilizando tomcat.
El proyecto esta creado con el IDE Intellij Idea.

```html
package com.example.prueba;

import java.io.*;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

### Esta es la clase Servlet sin tocar nada.
Luego agrego el servidor tomcat para acceder una vez levantado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### archivo web.xml sin tocar nada.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

</web-app>
```

### archivo index.jsp sin tocar nada.

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>
<br/>
<a href="hello-servlet">Hello Servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### Error al intentar acceder al Servlet:

[image: Intellij Idea]

Me gustaría acceder al Servlet pero no puedo.